# PCL App Development - Button not clickable following splash screen transition

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, portable-class-library

I am working on an app with a group of friends for a Twitch project.  I have recently integrated a splash animation when the app starts up. The only issue is, this splash animation renders my login button on the main page useless.  Now, if I move the button code, the button appears *before* the transition is complete (undesired result), but the button *will* work.  If I keep the code in place where the button shows up *post* transition (desired result), it isn't clickable (undesired result).  I'm sure you can see my frustration. The code is pasted below.  Please keep in mind I am very new to coding in general, so if this seems like a no-brainer, please have mercy.

**XAML for LoginPage:**

```
  <Grid>
    <Image x:Name="image" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
    <Button     HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                BackgroundColor="#008b8b" 
                Image="twitchtwo.png"
                Text="  Login using Twitch!" 
                FontSize="14"
                TextColor="White"
                Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    <Grid x:Name="SplashGrid" BackgroundColor="#007272">
      <Image  x:Name="Logo" 
              Source="logo" 
              HorizontalOptions="Center"
              VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Image.TranslationY>
          <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
            <On Platform="iOS">0</On>
            <On Platform="Android">-12</On>
          </OnPlatform>
        </Image.TranslationY>
      </Image>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

**C# code behind for LoginPage:**

```
{
  [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
  public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
  {
    public LoginPage()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      image.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("CCG.Images.ccgtext.png");
    }
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
      base.OnAppearing();
      await Task.Delay(2000);
      await Task.WhenAll(
        SplashGrid.FadeTo(0, 2000),
        Logo.ScaleTo(0, 250)
        );
    }
    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new TwitchAuth());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it using the 'IsVisible' property set to false.  Thanks Roger Leblanc for pointing me in the right direction.

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
      base.OnAppearing();

      await Task.Delay(2000);

      await Task.WhenAll(
        SplashGrid.FadeTo(0, 500),
        Logo.ScaleTo(0, 250)
        );
      SplashGrid.IsVisible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're fading your `SplashGrid` element, fading will set its opacity to whatever you specify it (0). The element is still over your page, but its opacity is 0. Just set the `Visibility` to `Collapsed` or `Hidden` after the fading is done.

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
  base.OnAppearing();
  await Task.Delay(2000);
  await Task.WhenAll(
    SplashGrid.FadeTo(0, 2000),
    Logo.ScaleTo(0, 250)
    );
  SplashGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Will update as soon as I try this out.

Comment: Unfortunately this yields the following: 'Grid' does not contain a definition for 'Visibility' and no extension method 'Visibility' accepting a first argument of type 'Grid' could be found. The name 'Visibility' does not exist in the current context.  Your answer, however, led me to something that did work, as I will post below.  Thanks again!